# Rotating reference object paths don't match

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, reference-frames

I am using two methods to calculate the path of an object in a rotating reference frame - one is using Euler's method to update the position based on the Centrifugal and Coriolis acceleration and the other one is using a rotation matrix to transform the inertial path of the object. I graphed them for **various launch angles** of the object:

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

However, if you look closely, you would notice that the paths are **not exactly identical**. (left is the one using rotation matrix and right is the one using Euler's method)

For the rotation matrix, I simply substitute the inertial position functions into a rotation matrix:
\begin{align}
R(x(t),y(t)) & = \begin{bmatrix}x(t)\cos\omega t - y(t)\sin\omega t \\ x(t)\sin\omega t + y(t)\cos\omega t \\ 0\end{bmatrix} \\ & = \begin{bmatrix}vt\cos\theta\cos\omega t - (vt\sin\theta-R)\sin\omega t \\ vt\cos\theta\sin\omega t - (vt\sin\theta-R)\cos\omega t \\ 0\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}
in which variable $R$ represents the raduis of the outter circle.

For the Euler's method, I calculate the acceleration based off this (I also set the step t to be very very small - 0.00001, so that shouldn't be a problem?):
$$a_0 = -\omega\times\left(\omega\times r_0\right)-2\omega
\times v_0$$

So my question is, why are the paths different? Shouldn't they be the same?

Comment: if the difference requires such close observation, can this not be just roundoff errors?

Comment: If you look at the difference as a function of elapsed time you should find it grows as some power of $t$. The numerical method will have a characteristic growth of error, and if they match then it is just what @ZeroTheHour says.

Comment: @CWPP Thank you for your comment! I understand that Euler's method has a good amount of error associated with the step size, but my other method, which uses a rotation matrix, would that have a possible error?

Comment: how you calculate the path from the acceleration ? if R is the rotation matrix so what is$ R\sin()$

Comment: @Eli i first calculate the initial acceleration from the initial velocity and position of the object. I then use that acceleration to update the initial velocity. I then use that velocity to update the position of the ball. The new set of velocity and position will then be used to update the acceleration. And this repeats

Comment: @Eli sorry about the notation. R in Rsin() represents the radius of the outter circle

Comment: @Steven Oh There's usually negliible error in a fairly simple analytic calculation, so it should just be down to the numerics of the differential equation solution.